# Conditional variance model with external regressors

Tags: estimators

I need to estimate the following conditional variance model

$$
y_t = \sigma_t\,\varepsilon_t
$$

where $y_t$ are the observed data, $\varepsilon_t$ are iid Normal shocks (zero-mean and unit-variance) and where the variance $\sigma_t$ is given by

$$
\sigma_t^2 = \omega+\sum_{j=1}^m\zeta_j\,v_{j,t}+\sum_{j=1}^{q}\,\alpha_j\,\varepsilon_{t-j}^2+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\beta_{j}\,\sigma_{t-j}^2,
$$

where $v_{j,t}$ with $j=1,...,m$ are $m$ external observed variables. I am asking whether I can find some efficient numerical routines, especially with Matlab/Octave.